# How to get information entered by the user using simple html login page in django view?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple login page returned by a django view. I need to get the information entered into the username and password boxes by the user. How can I get it without using forms in Django?

here is my view:

```
 def index(request):
      html="""<html>
      <title>Login</title>
      <body>
      <form name="MY Form"action="Login">
      userid<input type="text"name="text1">
      <br>password<input typy="password" name="text2">
      <br>
      <input type="submit"name="button1"value="login">
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
      """
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get POST parameters doing:

```
if request.method == 'POST':    
    userid = request.POST.get('text1' ,'')
```

Where the second string is the value if the parameter does not exist.